# Why is Magento ignoring my frontName?

Tags: magento

I'm following the tutorial on:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch

I'm creating a module called Rss in package MyPackage, my config looks as so:

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <MyPackage_Rss>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyPackage_Rss>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <rss>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyPackage_Rss</module>
                    <frontName>rss</frontName>
                </args>
            </rss>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
</config>
```

In the Admin area, under Configuration I see that the module is Enabled.

I have the IndexController.php setup in:

```
~/local/MyPackage/Rss/controllers/IndexController.php
```

However, when I go to my site:

http://mysite/rss

I get a 404.

Any thoughts?

Using latest Magento Enterprise

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you refresh all Magento's caches?

Comment: tried that, and tried a different frontname as well

Comment: Please remember, to do `rm -rf var/cache/mage--*` always after changing config files in Magento. I know, in this case the answer from clockworkgeek was correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a Mage_Rss module that uses the "rss" front name for itself. Try using a different front name.

Comment: Rename your <rss> tag to <mypackage_rss2> and try again because it is router name. You still have a conflict with core rss module due to the same router name.